# How to Extract Lyrics (USLT frame) from Mp3 using FFmpeg?

Tags: regex, audio, ffmpeg, metadata, mp3

I'm using Mp3tag's "Tools" feature to batch run FFmpeg in Windows, in order to batch extract the embedded lyrics content (USLT frame of [ID3v2 tag](https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0)) from MP3 files, I know with FFmpeg I can do something like:

```
-i "%_path%" -f ffmetadata "%_folderpath%\%_filename%.txt"
```

"%_path%" = full path of the MP3 file

"%_folderpath%%_filename%.txt" = path and filename of the exported txt file.

The command above extracts all the metadata from MP3 file and export them into a txt file with the following cotent for example:

```
;FFMETADATA1
album=name of the album
artist=name of the artist
title=name of the title
lyrics-eng=[00:01.23]line1 of lyrics
\
[00:04.56]line2 of lyrics
\
[00:07.89]line3 of lyrics
\
[01:03.12]3rd last line of lyrics
\
[02:04.34]2nd last line of lyrics
\
[03:05.67]Last line of lyrics
\

date=2020
encoder=Lavf59.23.100
```

(the original lyrics uses [Simple LRC format with timestamps in each line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(file_format)), certain lines contain only the timestamp with empty lyrics)

(There might (or might not) be additional metadata (e.g. [date and encoder in the example above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G55oF.png)) following the lyrics part)

As seen above, the backslash "\" (which is not present in the original lyrics) is somehow added after each line of lyrics, [between CR (CarriageReturn) and LF (LineFeed) as seen in Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V7K2.png) (the original lyrics use [CRLF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGqNq.png) as EOL characters).

So how do I **modify the given command line** to export **only** the lyrics part (**exluding all other metadata and the extra backslash "\"**), an example of the expected text file content is shown below:

```
[00:01.23]line1 of lyrics
[00:04.56]line2 of lyrics
[00:07.89]line3 of lyrics
[01:03.12]3rd last line of lyrics
[02:04.34]2nd last line of lyrics
[03:05.67]Last line of lyrics
```

with the original EOL characters from lyrics such as [CRLF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGqNq.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest that you remove all the unwanted `\` by searching for `\s*\\\s*` and replacing them with `\n`. (Test here: https://regex101.com/r/PEBWwm/1)
2. Then search for `(?<=lyrics-eng=)(?:[\w ]+\s)+` to capture all the lyrics without `\` between them. (Test here: https://regex101.com/r/8ad6kI/1)

Comment: Sorry I should have made the question more clear, each line of lyrics begins with a timestamp [mm:ss.xx] (I've editted the original question and updated all screenshots, please give it a re-read), perhaps it's possible to take advantage of the timestamps when locating the lyrics?

Also, I know how to do regex in Notepad++, but how do I incorporate the regex operations into the original command line (i.e. how to modify the example command line in the original question) so that it's automated?

Comment: @Wonderer I see, sorry I have no idea how to do incorporate regex to command line of ffmpeg. But as you said timestamp can be used to select lyrics in one step.

Answer (score 0):

This adds to @anothergatsby answer:

AFAIK, FFmpeg itself does not have a capability to return only a particular metadata tag, much less modifying the tag values. Your only option is to pipe the FFmpeg output to a regex-capable command (e.g., `sed` Linux command, handling the regex in a Python/PowerShell etc. script).

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i "%_path%" -f ffmetadata - | sed -n {regex_expr}  "%_folderpath%\%_filename%.txt"
```

Based on the text output path, it appears that you are in Windows env. If I were you I'd learn PowerShell scripting and its regex support.

Comment: if ffmpeg wasn't possible, how about ffprobe? which seems to be designed more for this kind of application.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're looking for is this:

```
(\[[0-9].*)
```

I've no clue about how to do the editing while extracting the lyrics or with the command prompt in anyway.
If you can't find a better way and know python a bit, you can create a python script with the below code put it inside a folder that contains **only** the files you want to edit and run.

```
import re
import os


def main():

    for file in os.listdir():
        with open(file, "r+") as f:
            lyrics = re.findall(r"(\[[0-9].*)", f.read())
            f.truncate(0)
            f.seek(0)
            for lyric in lyrics:
                f.write(lyric + "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```